# How Do we use Lightning Threading Tokens in L.Flow Custom MetaData Case auto-replies?

Tags: lightning

We are disabling RefId (ThreadId) Case mgmt.
We have Enabled Lightning Threading in a sandbox and are testing.
*** We use a Lightning Flow to generate Email-to-Case auto-replies - which are created as custom metadata type rows  (.mdt)   Each has an HTML Template Body, Subject  where we are using Threading Tokens.  Example  {{{Case.Thread_Token}}}
1- Case gets created in SFDC
2- AutoReply is received at Sender side email but token values are not set

- they show up as {{{Case.Thread_Token}}}
  3 - AutoReply does not show up in SFDC Case

Any advice?  My 1st thought is to update Lightning Flow to retrieve Threading Tokens
but I'll wait a bit in case someone has discovered something in this same scenario?
Standard Email-to-Case but not using Email Templates and Email Alerts
rather we are using Email-to-Case and Lightning Flow which calls custom meta data and Sends autoReply based Flow criteria, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Case Email Alerts to send your emails?  Sadly, according to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.support_email_to_case_threading.htm&type=5), those are the only templates that can use the [Case.Thread_Token](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.merge_fields_cases.htm&language=en_US&type=5) merge field.

However, you can also get the token from the apex method [getFormattedThreadingToken(CaseId)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.248.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_System_EmailMessages_getFormattedThreadingToken.htm),

So you could write some logic that invokes that apex class & stores the token somewhere (perhaps in your Custom Metadata or in a Case field).